# Doubts in cloudera manager installation

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Can anyone Please clarify me, i have a only 4gb Ram laptop with windows 7  installed ,currently i have working with Apache distributed hadoop1.x in a vmware,i want to practice Cloudera distributed hadoop with cloudera manager ,can you please tell how to install cloudera manager in 2gb ram allocated vmware.is it possible  to install cloudera using cloudera manager in 2gb Ram allocated VMWARE with Redhat linux 6 installed?if yes can anyone tell me steps to install it in vmware with only 2gb Ram Size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In short:  While running a CM cluster instance in pseudo-distributed mode on a 2GB VM is theoretically possible, due to the resource constraints it may lead to a sub-par user experience and is therefore not recommended.  It's strongly advised to consider either installing CM or using the existing Cloudera Quickstart VM on a machine with no less than 4GB RAM available (after OS overhead).

Reasoning:
The 2GB of RAM will have to be divvied up between all of the selected components chosen at the time of installation (e.g. HDFS, YARN). Given a barebones configuration (HDFS + YARN), this will require the 2GB to be spread among the following services:  NameNode, Secondary NameNode, DataNode, ResourceManager, NodeManager,JobHistoryServer, Cloudera Manager Web UI, PostgreSQL or whatever DB backend was chosen at the time of install, and Cloudera Manager Management services (if configured).

This would yield approx. 8-9 applications/services that would be constricted to using anywhere from 128MB - 256MB each, which depending on usage, could lead to utilization challenges such as GC thrashing, OOMs, or even CPU and RAM contention.